# Returning fields with the same name from different tables in a data.table join

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.table objects in my R workspace that share multiple variable names. I want to join them on one of the variables that they have in common but display both values of the other.

```
people<-data.table(name=c('Joe','Bob','Adam'),
               zip=c(98112,98101,61604),
               )
setkey(people,name)

address<-data.table(zip=c(98112,61604,94521),
                    state=c('WA','IL','CA'),
                    name=c('Puget Sound','Central IL','SF Bay Area')
                    )
setkey(address,zip)

address[J(people$zip),.(state,name),people[,.(zip,name)]]
   name   zip state name
1: Adam 61604    IL Adam
2:  Bob 98101    NA  Bob
3:  Joe 98112    WA  Joe
```

The join is returning the people$name twice. How do I get it to return people$name once and address$name once?

Comment: I don't understand what that `..., by = people[, zip, by = name]` part is supposed to do - can you please explain what you're trying to do here?

Comment: perhaps you simply want `setkey(people, zip); address[people]`?

Comment: That does generate the output I want, but it had two other problems
1) it doesn't make sense conceptually. I use name to identify people, not zip code
2) it only works for when I am trying to map in information from the zip code. if I also had, for example, a person's month of birth and wanted to look up their birth stone, then setting zip as the key doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: your `address` `data.table` doesn't have names of people, so I don't know what "making sense conceptually" means for you - as-is the field that binds the two tables together, i.e. the `key` of the join, is the zip code. I don't know what #2 means - add an example.

Comment: 1) I'm already using zip as a key in address; that makes sense. using zip as the key for people doesn't

2) if I also had, for example, a person's month of birth and wanted to look up their birth stone, then setting zip as the key doesn't allow me to look up their birthstone

Comment: I think you're confused about what a `key` in the context of `data.table` merges is. It's the moral equivalent of the `by` argument in the base `merge` function and is simply the columns on which you will merge, so it is only conceptually meaningful when merging, but not on its own.

Comment: So the "standard use" of keys in data.table is that you re-key a table each time you subset, aggregate, or join (all of which are sped up by keys)?

Comment: No, the "standard use" is to only key for joining. The speedups you get from the `data.table` being sorted along particular columns for other operations are generally insignificant.